# How to get into video game writing?

Tags: jobs

I'm an excellent writer with a talent for crafting characters, worlds, and plotlines of a unique and appealing nature. For some reason I'm studying computer science, but I know fiction writing is my true calling.

How can I find an entry-level job or internship developing the stories, characters, and dialogue for a video game? That would be my dream job, and I know I could make a superb showing.

Any tips on where I can find opportunities? Google searches turned up a ton of game design jobs, but I think that's different. I couldn't find anything related to writing.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 to @Aerovistae for the appreciation of the appreciation of the appreciation!

Comment: We need to go deeper.

Comment: Drop me an email (see profile), I may have the opportunity you're looking for.

Comment: @psycketom There is in fact no valid contact information in your profile. Most of the links are dead. :)

Comment: @Aerovistae Hmm, I think the email should be visible, anyways - toms.seisums@gmail.com (wont provide the company one for spam reasons).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not have personal experience doing this so my suggestions are just speculation. 
(this is just how I would do it)

Firstly, you'll need a portfolio for your writing, developed characters, manifested environment/world descriptions ect...

You'll need to showcase your abilities in this way to allow people to explore the possibility of you being a good fit as a writer for their project.

I would research small and indie companies to see what sort of projects they are working on and find a few you would like to contact and pursue. If and after you've written successfully for a few games (or one game if you are plenty happy with the results) then you can start to broaden your horizons and look towards bigger and better projects/companies.

Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend attending any game and/or mobile development meetups you can.
There you will find more than a few folks that have the opposite situation...they understand the programming end of things, but can't wrap a story around their pixels.  Talk with them (and listen!).
In the meantime, develop a storyboard for a game.  Start with your favorite genre (tower defense, 1st person shooter, whatever) and write a concise description of the world/environment, the characters and objects, and the game play.  Think of this as your "elevator pitch", something that you can use to quickly show a developer in a 5 minute read what you are able to do.

Answer (score 2):

Game design is different, but related. The couple guys I know who work as narrative designers (ie. they craft the stories for RPGs) started in the industry as level designers, and from there demonstrated to their boss that they were really passionate about the storyline.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for your confidence... I would simply suggest sending résumés to multiple game companies. Attach a few pages with on each a chapter or two describing or telling bits of stories about individual characters. This should attract attention.

If you are as good as you say, with your Computer Science background you will land a job in the industry at some point.

But don't **stop at small companies**. Larger structures have more budget for background stories and narrative work.

Answer (score 2):

Like anything else you want to excel at:  practice it.  So in other words start writing.  And writing and writing and writing.  And keep reading and developing your appreciation for the craft.

Participate in [nanowrimo](http://www.nanowrimo.org/).  Try and get a book deal, or to publish short stories somewhere.  I think the way that works is you shop your *finished story* around to try to get it published.  When you have some stories out that people can read, they can more easily select/recruit.